# Is there a method to increase the gap between two lines in c++ ColorText function?

Tags: c++, c++11

[image]

is there a method to increase the gap between these lines in c++?

I felt that all the text are too near to each other, I want to increase the gap between those lines.

original code:

```
void ColorText(int color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
}

int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
    system_boot();
    ColorText(1761); 
    userInput(); //ignore this, some code doing some other functional stuff

    return 0;
}
```

what I've tried:

```
int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
    system_boot();
    ColorText(1761); //1999 //1770 //1777 //1725 //1765 //1761
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl; //I applied endl here
    userInput();

    return 0;
}
```

However, it hasn't got me to the solution, I guess that changes should be made at the SetConsoleTextAttribute in ColorText function , but I can't find any related documentation on that, so I seek help from here.

Best i can think of is I can directly add endl to those printed text, but it is very lengthy and inefficient, and also adding an endl will just print out another empty line only, like below
[image]

It wasn't my initial motive, which is just increase / widen the gap and space of a particular line

Comment: No, terminals have a fixed line height, if you want detailed control over text layout use a gui

Comment: sure, does that mean that if i still insist on widen the gap, by not using gui , the only option is using endl to manually seperate the spaces?